# A manual page layout strategy for iOS app instead of storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, layout

I am well versed in android but somewhat new to iOS.

I have been working with the storyboard layout system of xcode to create my initial pages, but I am much more interested in dynamic page creation.

My requirements are really quite simple.

I have a thread in which the user selects a layout, then I perform a segue to that page.
However I am tired of the complications of the storyboard and figure there must be a simplier way.

I have functions that I can call which will layout a particular page to my specifications.

In android I do it like this:

I have an layout on the screen with a object defined in a particular location on the screen.
I then just connect the layout I want to the particular object.

Rather than redrawing the whole page with segues between storyboard pages which creates much duplication I would prefer something simplier.

here is pseudo code:

```
(ui thread)
display root layout (with hook/frame/object to contain subview)
user pushed button in root window to change layout
popup dialog asking which layout
send msg to render code

(render thread)   
switch (whichLayout)
   case A: connect layout A to subview; break
   case B: connect layout B to subview; break
   ...
```

I have constructors for the views, the root layout, and the popups. In the iOS world I have a tableCollection or a gridCollection as a class which can be invoked to do the work, however, as I mentioned above I am recreating the entire display page with seques and would prefer not to.

I suspect I am missing some simple concept which is buried under storyboard.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're looking for functionally, but sounds like a navigation controller might be helpful (maybe)?  I'd err towards using more, simpler view controllers than fewer, more complex ones.  Also, when you switch platforms and find something that seems stupid or complex, there's an instinct to struggle against it, trying to recreate your old comfortable approach.  That's usually when one invents something stupidly complex on the new platform.  My advice here begins with the phrase "When in Rome...".

Comment: I think my trouble is my dislike of using a mouse, or for that matter a GUI.  Using the storyboard to layout an app seems endlessly complex. But as you say and I am currently doing as the Romans do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My trouble came from introducing myself to iOS development through the tutorials on the Apple site which lead me down the path of stories boards, navigation controllers, and segues.

When I finally closed my eyes and looked past the pretty doo-dads and blinky-lights and instead understood the programatic way of doing things all became clear.

To answer my own question: the solution is quite simple (though I am sure all sane iOS developers will use the navigation contoller).

I can plop a new view on top of an existing view and then remove it or hide it.

Say 'case A' is my example above is to display a table view:

```
case A:
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height);
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    ... populate the table view ...
    [self.window addSubview:myTableView];
    break;
```

When switching to another case I remove the case A tableview and then create my case B view and so on:

```
[myTableView removeFromSuperview];
...
```

Alternately rather than create / destroy I could hide views so I do not always have to recreate them using

```
[self.window sendSubviewToBack:myTableView];
```

and then later:

```
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:myTableView];
```